# Call a function after all currently scheduled callbacks are executed (node)

Tags: javascript, node.js, events, callback

I am using a streaming `multipart/form-data` parser to handle file and field uploads. Whenever a new field or file is parsed an event is fired and I perform some processing. After all fields and files are parsed a `'close'` event is fired where I then call a termination function for the request. Here is the setup.

```
parser.on('fields',function(){

    handleField(callback);

});


parser.on('close',function(){
    dismiss();
})
```

The problem is that handling a field might take some time which makes the 'close' listener dismiss the request before I have a chance to invoke the callback from the field processing listener.

I have tried to use the `setImmediate` function which according to its description

> queues its callbacks in the event queue after I/O and timer callbacks.

in order to have my `dismiss()` function be invoked after all currently scheduled callbacks are executed but that didn't work and I have even tried `process.nextTick()` in case I had the order reversed, but no such luck.

So question is, how could I call my `dismiss()` function only after all currently scheduled callbacks from the processing function are called?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) and [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all), you can make your `dismiss` a future operation that depends on the resolution of all Promises that get resolved by a wrapper function of your callback(s).

The trick is to wrap your callback into another function that resolves or rejects the wrapper Promise after the callback has been called by the asynchronous (or synchronous) operation. You can store all the Promises in an array and then call `Promise.all` on that array to yield another Promise to `.then()` on.

In this example, I'll be assuming that `callback` is a Node I/O-style handler (i.e. first argument is `err`) and `handleField` is an asynchronous Node I/O-style operation that eventually calls `callback`. From the statement *"Whenever a new field or file is parsed an event is fired and I perform some processing."*, I'm also making the assumption that 'fields' is an event which occurs N times where N is the number of fields and thus N callbacks must be completed before you can correctly `dismiss()`. Feel free to comment if my assumptions are incorrect.

```
var promises = [];

parser.on('fields', function() {
  promises.push(
    new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {

      // wrap the original callback into another function.
      // this function either resolves or rejects the Promise.
      handleField(function(err) {
        // if there's an error,
        // pass it to reject instead of throwing it.
        if (err) {
          reject(err);
        } else {
          // calls your callback with given args.
          // resolves Promise with return value of callback.
          resolve(callback.apply(null, arguments));
        }
      });

    })
  );
});


parser.on('close', function() {
  Promise.all(promises).then(function(values) {
    dismiss(); // All resolved.
  }, function(reason) {
    console.error(reason.stack); // First reject.
    process.exit(); // Exit on error.
  });
});
```

To learn Promises, you should read the Mozilla documentation or some other reputable reference or tutorial, but I've added some key points below that should help you.

---

**new Promise(fn)**

When you create a new Promise using the constructor, the function you pass in gets *immediately invoked*. This is necessary for starting asynchronous tasks immediately and then being able to respond to their results as early as possible using the `.then()` interface. Within the function that you pass in, you can `resolve` or `reject` the Promise however you choose.

---

**Using Promise.all**

> The Promise.all(iterable) method returns a promise that resolves when
>   all of the promises in the iterable argument have resolved, or rejects
>   with the reason of the first passed promise that rejects.

The important thing to note is that the following:

```
Promise.all([
  new Promise((resolve, reject) => setTimeout(() => resolve('work done'), 3000)),
  new Promise((resolve, reject) => reject('coffee depleted'))
]).then(
  (v) => console.log('all work done!'),
  (r) => console.error(`Error: ${r}`)
)
```

will *immediately* reject without waiting for the 1st Promise to resolve because the 2nd Promise gives an early error The first Promise in the array will still eventually resolve, but the point is that `Promise.all` rejects early, which is good.

---

**Shim**

If you are running an old version of Node without Promises, you can install the [Promises library](https://github.com/then/promise) which is an open source implementation available on GitHub.

```
npm install promise --save
```

Then just `require` it:

```
var Promise = require('promise');
```

---

**es6-promisify**

You could [promisify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/es6-promisify) the asynchronous function `handleFields` assuming that it's an asynchronous Node I/O-style operation that calls callback with `err` as its first argument:

```
// npm install es6-promisify --save
var promisify = require("es6-promisify")

handleField = promisify(handleField);
promises.push(
  handleField().then(function(successArgs) {
    // success callback here
  }).catch(function(err) {
    console.error(err);
  })
);
```

Overall, this looks pretty clean. If you're using the Promise library, then just use [`Promise.denodify(fn)`](https://github.com/then/promise#promisedenodeifyfn).

Comment: Within the wrapper function that is the callback passed into the handleField() function how would I resolve errors?  I am assuming I would call reject() if there is an error. Correct?

Comment: @naughtyboy Correct :) `reject` takes one argument which is the error reason.

Comment: and that error is then passed into the function supplied to `.then()`? Because what I previously had was `handleField(function(err,number){ if(err){  //end the request  } else  {  //do something with number   }    })`      now the callback should look something like `function resolveCallback(err, number){ if(err) {  reject(err) // do not end request  }else{ resolve(callback(number)) }  }`  so that now the previously supplied callback would not deal with any errors (sorry for the horrible editing I dont know how to add a new line without submitting).

Comment: oh and one last thing, the functions commence their execution only once `Promise.all(iterable)` is called correct?

Comment: When you do `new Promise(fn)`, the function `fn` is called *immediately*. This is useful since you want to start the asynchronous processing right away and then react to its completion at a later time. This method would be terribly slow if you had to wait for Promise.all to be called before doing any fields processing. To see this in action, try `new Promise(function() { console.log(42) } )` You'll see that console.log gets called almost immediately.

Comment: @naughtyboy Yes, `resolveCallback` gets passed `err` so you can just `reject(err)` right there if there is one and `resolve` otherwise.

Comment: Alright all I needed to know Shashank, you are the master of us all. Thanks.

Comment: One quick thing you forgot to mention now that I am testing it is that if there is an error and you reject a promise the first function passed into .then() will not be invoked so you must specify a second one..

Comment: @naughtyboy True...I've added a small example with `Promise.all` where I show the handling of a rejection by passing in a second function. :) I've used ES6 features for brevity and clarity.

Answer (score 2):

One possibility is to use a library that turns NodeJS callback API calls into calls that return *promises*. Promises are then easy to compose. There are a couple of node-to-promises libs out there, such as [`promisify`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/es6-promisify). (I haven't used it, can't vouch, just an example.)

But without going down that path, the usual answer is to have both callback call a central "done" method that knows how many calls are outstanding:

```
var calls = 0;

++calls;
parser.on('fields',function(){

    handleField(callback);
    done();
});

++calls;
parser.on('close',function(){
    done();
})

function done() {
    if (--calls == 0) {
        dismiss();
    }
}
```

You can even encapsulate that into a utility object:

```
// ES2015 (ES6); ES5 translation below
class Tracker {
    constructor(callback) {
        this.count = 0;
        this.callback = callback;
    }

    start() {
        ++this.count;
    }

    stop() {
        if (--this.count) {
            this.callback();
        }
    }
}
```

Then

```
var track = new Tracker(function() {
    dismiss();
});

track.start();
parser.on('fields',function(){

    handleField(callback);
    track.stop();
});

track.start();
parser.on('close',function(){
    track.stop();
})
```

And yes, it's a bit fiddly, which is why promises were invented. :-)

---

ES5 translation of `Tracker`:

```
function Tracker(callback) {
    this.count = 0;
    this.callback = callback;
}

Tracker.prototype.start = function() {
    ++this.count;
};

Tracker.prototype.stop = function() {
    if (--this.count) {
        this.callback();
    }
};
```

Comment: Thanks for your input and creativity in solving my problem. I would just feel more comfortable using the promises library now that I've read a bit more about it.